# Grants to OR visibility of a specific index in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, database-indexes, lob

I have a somewhat strange question to ask: can I somehow hide a specific index from a specific user in Oracle 11g, yet let this user select from the table of this index?

The anamnesis is as follows: there is a table with one field of BLOB type. Oracle created internal index for that table on that column:

```
SELECT index_name, index_type, uniqueness, 
       temporary, generated, secondary, visibility FROM DBA_INDEXES         
 WHERE table_name = 'SIGNERS_BLOBS_TABLE'
```

returns

```
INDEX_NAME                INDEX_TYPE  UNIQUENESS TEMPORARY GENERATED SECONDARY VISIBILITY 
------------------------- ----------- ---------- --------- --------- --------- ---------- 
SYS_IL0009096175C00002$$  LOB         UNIQUE     N         Y         N         VISIBLE
```

And this index I need to hide from a specific user. Yet this same user has to be able to select from that SIGNERS_BLOBS_TABLE.

Comment: What does "hiding" an index do/ accomplish (i.e. is this application running a data dictionary query and showing the results to the user and you want to avoid showing this index to the user because it is confusing?  Are you trying to somehow prevent the user from using this index in their queries?  Something else?)

Comment: You can't get rid of the LOB index. Oracle needs that to manage the BLOB

Comment: > **Justin Cave**

The developer had displayed me a fact that when he runs his program with not really powerful user - the program starts normally. Yet when we runs the same program with another user that is almost as powerful as schema owner - the program fails to run with strange error message that calls this index somewhat malformed. So I'd like to try to hide the index from that more powerful user.

Comment: > **a_horse_with_no_name** <br/> Yeap. I can't even hide it for all except Oracle optimizer as described in Burleson's article.
>! it throws an exception that LOB index can't be dropped or altered.

Comment: What is the exact error?  Is the application actually supposed to be dropping or altering any indexes?  If this is a third party application, it sounds like an application bug that needs to be addressed to the application vendor.

Comment: If you really (really, really) want to work around a buggy application (and you have a high tolerance for hacky solutions), you can trace the queries the application generates, find the queries it is running (presumably hitting something like `all_indexes`) and create a view called `all_indexes` in the user's schema that selects from the real `sys.all_indexes` with an additional filter.  I guarantee that this will bite you at some point (if only when a new Oracle version adds a new column to the real view that you don't add to yours) and it will be a pain to debug but it does work.

Comment: @JustinCave </br> I do not have an exact error. All I understood is that the dev guy added a third party library to his 3rd party (as far as Oracle products are concerned - it is a 3rd or even 4th party, he-he) program he develops in. And this lib is _capable of checking Ora indexes for validity_. :)  Of course I do believe that it checks them in a wrong and undeveloped way as I suspect it doesn't even aware of the LOB type of index. But I just wanted to be 100% sure that I did my best to try to help the dev guy.

Comment: Surely the "dev guy" can give you the exact error.  Depending on the error, you can trace what the library is trying to do in order to figure out whether it is actually trying to run DDL against your database (which would presumably be a strong reason to suggest that the developer find a different library).

Comment: And as far as I see - I did my best. Of course I will not develop a workaround like `all_indexes` view. That would be a hell of a job for me as well as for the dev guy - he'd be responcible for communicating with code owners of that 3rd party program to help him to customize/ teach that lib to use my view instead of what they use now. So my _well grounded_ solution for the dev guy would be just to throw the lib away. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, Oracle does not support grants on indexes. 
@Justin Cave, thank you for all the additional info.